# insmod works in 6.5 OS but not 7.3 OS - shows module verification failed:

Tags: module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am facing an issue in porting custom pci driver in kernel 3.10 (7.3 OS). Kernel crashes when doing ioctl access or any access to the driver. Doubt whether the crash is because of the below message,

> Warning:- 
>   [  629.090891]_pcie: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
>   [  629.090921] pcie: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel.

But I am not facing this warning/error when I port the same driver in RHEL OS 6.5.

Will disabling kernel module signature in linux 7.3 and booting custom OS clear this warning? Or is there anyway to clear the warning without recompiling OS.

Answer (score 0):

The cited message itself is not the reason of the crash. "Kernel tainting" is a notice for kernel developers that user has loaded a module that does not originate from environment friendly to kernel developers. Some people consider this as a valid reason not to support such users and/or setups.

The reason of crash is that internal kernel ABI (binary interfaces) is not stable, it does change between versions (and even between different configurations of the same version). Kernel has some protection against loading binary-incompatible modules but that is often disabled and/or can be bypassed. And once binary-incompatible module gets inside kernel, attempt to execute it often causes crashes and other misbehavior: module was compiled for different ABI and thus code inside module tries to access structure fields at wrong offsets, call functions with parameters in wrong registers, and so on.

To avoid crash, module must be at least recompiled against kernel you are running. Though this can fail in case of there was a change not only in ABI but also in API. In the later case, porting module's source to updated API is required.